# Can I check if create_ap works?

Tags: bash, shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wifi-hotspot

I am currently using [the script `create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) to emit a Wifi Access Point (WAP) using my Raspberry Pi, which is running Raspbian. How can I check if the AP is up and running using a bash script?

For your information, here is how I start it :

```
create_ap --ieee80211n --ht_capab '[HT40+]' -n wlan0 $ESSID $PWD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by the creator in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/173), a check like the following one will do the trick :

```
if [[ create_ap --list-running | grep wlan0 | wc -l -ge 1 ]]
then
    echo "It works !!"
fi
```

How it works :

```
create_ap --list-running : shows all the interfaces on which create_ap is running
grep wlan0 : get the lines where we can find the interface
wc -l : count the lines
```